# Why doesn't PIPESTATUS work on pipelines within a command substitution

Tags: bash, pipe, command-substitution

Proof below:  Bash 4

```
Prompt> $(echo hello|sed 's/h/m/'|xargs -I{} ls {} 2>/dev/null|sed 's/ /_/')
Prompt> for i in ${PIPESTATUS[@]}; do echo $i;done
Output> 0

Prompt> echo hello|sed 's/h/m/'|xargs -I{} ls {} 2>/dev/null|sed 's/ /_/'
Prompt> for i in ${PIPESTATUS[@]}; do echo $i;done
Output> 0
Output> 0
Output> 123
Output> 0
```

Is command substitution not considered to be run in a foreground shell?  that's my guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the command substitution is run in subshell, so it made no change to the `PIPESTATUS` variable of the parent shell. From [Command Execution Environment](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Execution-Environment.html) documentation:

> Command substitution, commands grouped with parentheses, and
>   asynchronous commands are invoked in a subshell environment that is a
>   duplicate of the shell environment, except that traps caught by the
>   shell are reset to the values that the shell inherited from its parent
>   at invocation. Builtin commands that are invoked as part of a pipeline
>   are also executed in a subshell environment. Changes made to the
>   subshell environment cannot affect the shell’s execution environment.

You can get the expected result if you check the `PIPESTATUS` variable in the subshell:

```
$ printf '%s\n' $(echo hello|sed 's/h/m/'|xargs -I{} ls {} 2>/dev/null|sed 's/ /_/';
for i in ${PIPESTATUS[@]}; do echo $i;done)
0
0
123
0
```

Comment: That's what I thought. I wanted to assign a variable with command substitution using a pipeline, and take action if any element of PIPESTATUS was != 0.  I ended up skipping command substitution and using `read VAR < <(pipeline)` to work around it.